# EAS build error when doing internal distribution build Android

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, expo

I can't locate the issue of why my build is failing. The project is fairly empty for now as I'm just trying to set up a React Native project

```
    [stderr]    ... 36 more
    [stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [stderr] * What went wrong:
    [stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
    [stderr] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
    [stderr]    > There was a failure while executing work items
    [stderr]       > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
    [stderr]          > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
    [stderr]            Type org.reactnative.maskedview.BuildConfig is defined multiple  times:/home/expo/workingdir/build/ReactNativeTest/node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view/android/build/.transforms/1fede80f5722d6eb9b5a88c8f8c99d86/transformed/classes/classes.dex, /home/expo/workingdir/build/ReactNativeTest/node_modules/@react-native-masked-view/masked-view/android/build/.transforms/2db9fab16a0305b47f184ccd5344fe0e/transformed/classes/classes.dex
    [stderr]            Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    [stderr] * Try:
    [stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    [stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    [stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [stderr] BUILD FAILED in 7m 16s
    Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

As I'm not sure what is relevant information I'll add as much as possible.
Few things I've tried:

- Doing a prebuild of Android
- At Path android/app/build.gradle adding:

  ```
  defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true //Add this line
  }
  ```

and

```
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

- `java --version` gives:

```
     java 18.0.2.1 2022-08-18
     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

- `./gradlew --version` gives:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-12-22 12:37:54 UTC
Revision:     6f556c80f945dc54b50e0be633da6c62dbe8dc71

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          18.0.2.1 (Oracle Corporation 18.0.2.1+1-1)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.5.1 x86_64
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "reactnativetest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito-sans": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.3",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-cli": "^6.0.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.5",
    "i18n-js": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Error occurs when doing : `eas build --profile development --platform android`

I have been doing android development on Android Studio without any issues for a year or so. I am not used to React Native yet. Opening project in Expo Go works, but not building it.